# How to reference an external library on a Custom Function Office AddIn for Excel?

Tags: javascript, excel, office-addins

In this Custom Function Office Add-In project, I need a base64 function.

I am testing the add-in in an installed Office 365 Excel (Version 1908).

I tried to use `btoa` but it is not available for the add-in.

So I tried to use the **base-64** library and the **Crypto-js**, putting a `<script>` tag at the functions.html, before the closing body tag, but I could not reference the functions. I used these CDNs, respectively, to import each of the libraries: https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/Base64/1.1.0/base64.js and https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/crypto-js/4.0.0/enc-base64.js.

I also did a `npm install crypto-js base-64 --save` and tried to use the `import { xxx } from "library";` statement at my functions.ts, with no success either: the add-in does not even load.

The project was generated with the https://yeoman.io/.

How can I reference an external library in my Office add-in?

Answer (score 0):

So, a teammate figured it out: we were doing `from { } import "xxx"` right after the function decorator. Changed to the beginning and it worked.